# XQuery: Setting privileges to solve " Request time limit exceeds the maximum allowed " error

Tags: xquery, marklogic, privileges, time-limiting

When I try to run a query, I got the following error: `Time limit exceeded`. I tried to increase request time limit to **8000** using the following code:

```
for ..... 
return ( xdmp:set-request-time-limit(8000), myquery)
```

I've got the following error `XDMP-TIMELIMIT: xdmp:set-request-time-limit(8000) -- Request time limit exceeds the maximum allowed`.

The `xdmp:set-request-time-limit` function requires one of the following priviliges:

```
http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-set-request-time-limit-any
```

**Or**

```
http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-set-request-time-limit-my
```

I'm facing a problem in setting these privileges. This is where I declare them:

```
for ..... 
return (xdmp:set-request-time-limit(8000), xdmp:privilege("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-set-request-time-limit-any","execute"), myquery)
```

But I'm still getting the `Request time limit exceeds the maximum allowed` error. I guess I'm declaring them in the wrong place. Any help

NOTES:

- The screenshot shows my http server settings. [image: server settings]
- The default user is nobody
- I'm using Qqonsole to run the query

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the app server whose screen shot you're sharing isn't the app server for QConsole port.

Comment: No,  I have selected the same server from the Content Source drop down list in QConsole.

Comment: QConsole is a web application.  It runs on its own HTTP port (8000).  And the timeout settings that apply to requests issued into QConsole will be those configured for the QConsole port (8000).